# Transferring DHCP using Windows Server Migration Tool - Why is Powershell is crashing on the import of the .mig file?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, dhcp, migration, windows-server-2003-r2

I am migrating DHCP from a windows server 2003R2 DC to a Windows Server 2008R2 DC

I've followed this video and its predecessor (Installing Windows Server Migration Tools)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/migrating-dhcp-using-the-windows-server-2008-r2-migration-tools.aspx

I went through everything smoothly until the last step. I have exported a .mig file with my DHCP configuration on the old 2003r2 server. I transferred this .mig file over to my 2008R2 server, when running the import command, it will appear to work for a minute or two and then I get a generic windows "Powershell has stopped working" error and I have to close the program.

Under the problem details I see the following:

FileVersionOfSystemManagementAutomation:  6.1.7600.16385

InnermostExceptionType:    System.AccessViolationException
OutermostExceptionType:    System.AccessViolationException
DeepestPowerShellFrame:    unknown
OS Version:                6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
LocaleID:                  1033

Seems like there are permissions issues maybe? I am running powershell as an admin and am logged in to the server as a domain administrator.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the script and watch what POWERSHELL.EXE is doing using Process Monitor (procmon) from Microsoft's SysInternals.